# Differentiation of composite function with respect to a function

Tags: derivatives

\begin{align*}
\frac {d\phi(q(t))}{dq(t)} &= \frac {d\phi(q(t))}{dq(t)} \cdot \frac {dt}{dt}\\
&= \frac {\frac{d\phi(q(t))}{dt}}{\frac{dq(t)}{dt}}\\
&= \frac{q'(t)*\phi'(q(t))}{q'(t)}\\ 
&= \phi'(q(t)
\end{align*}

surely this isn't correct?

Comment: Why do you think it's not correct?

Comment: Really I am hoping it is incorrect because that means my issue is somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you called $q(t)$ some other name, say $x$, what would you get...?